# How can one import Node.js dependencies in Next.js 13 middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Following middleware throws “Error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'constants' module.”.

For pages, I typically use [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-server-side-props).

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { readFile } from "fs-extra"

export const middleware = async () => {
  const data = await readFile("./foo", "utf-8")
  const response = NextResponse.next()
  return response
}

export const config = {
  matcher: "/((?!_next|api|favicon.ico|favicon.png).*)?",
}
```